# Does « pour que » ever get contracted?

Tags: grammaire, registre-familier

In the film *Intouchables*, Driss says the line « Donnez-moi le top que je lui remette les idées en place. » I just wanted to ask here if the « que » is a shortened form of « pour que » in this case and do French people do this in informal language or is my script faulty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a shortend form for "pour que" or in a more sustained language "afin que", You can use it but with mesure because it's a bit I don't know how to say it but kind of outdated or rustic.